# Start function as a background job with start-job

Tags: function, powershell, start-job

I am trying to start a function with start-job.
For some reason, I cannot get it to work, the global variables wont pass.
My question would be - how to pass global variables to the function and than to start-job without declaring them inside the function.
Function example:

```
 $OutputDirectory=c:\test
 $zipfile="c:\1.zip"

    function 7zipextraction
{
    Set-Alias 7zip $7zip_path
    # Extracting files
    $extract = 7zip x -y $zipfile -o"$OutputDirectory"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {
        
        write-host "7zip Error"
        
        return
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Files extracted successfully"
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    
}
```

Examples from start-job:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:7zipextraction} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Use [`-ArgumentList` to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2#example-10--use-the-argumentlist-parameter-to-specify-an-array) pass the arguments.

Comment: I tried it... didn't work

Comment: your function needs a `param($path)`. Then you could use the `-argumentlist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`using:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#the-using-scope-modifier) modifier to access variables that are outside your script block:

```
$OutputDirectory='c:\test'
$zipfile='c:\1.zip'
$7zippath = 'C:\path\to\7zip'

function 7zipextraction
{
    Set-Alias 7zip $using:7zippath
    # Extracting files
    $extract = 7zip x -y $using:zipfile -o"${using:OutputDirectory}"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {
        
        write-host "7zip Error"
        
        return
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Files extracted successfully"
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:7zipextraction} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

`using` works with script blocks executed on remote computers or in a different thread:

- Invoke-Command
- Start-Job
- Start-ThreadJob
- ForEach-Object -Parallel

Comment: Thanks!! And what if I have a variable with extension?  example - $progressbar1.Name
I tried - $using:progressbar1.Name

Comment: No problem! Try: `($using:progressbar1).Name`

Comment: Thanks !! it worked.  Now what about calling a global function from the 7zipextraction? Is it possible? I get function name is not recognized

Comment: Start-Job fires up another instance of powershell to run the ScriptBlock passed to it. All the variables prepended with using get serialized and then passed to the new powershell instance. There's no access to the scope from which Start-Job is called. You can save your global function in a file and dot-source that file in 7zipextraction, or if it's a function from a module, you have to explicitly import that module in your 7zipextraction function.

Answer (score 3):

`Start-Job` dispatches the job to *a separate child process*, which is why it doesn't have access to the variables you've defined in the calling process.

Parameterize all variables in the function and then pass the appropriate arguments explicitly to `Start-Job -ArgumentList`:

```
function 7zipextraction
{
    param(
        [string]$ZipFile,
        [string]$OutputDirectory,
        [string]$7zipPath
    )

    Set-Alias 7zip $7zipPath -Force

    # Extracting files
    $extract = 7zip x -y $zipfile -o"$OutputDirectory"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {
        write-host "7zip Error"
        return
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Files extracted successfully"
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:7zipextraction} -ArgumentList "c:\1.zip","c:\test","c:\path\to\7zip\7z.exe" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```